# Possible to develop a game using assembly language?

Tags: assembly

I am wondering what it takes to develop a game in assembly language. For example, what are the limitations or advantages from using assembly language in game development? Also, are there any programs/softwares to aid the development of games in assembly language?

Comment: Yes, it is possible; roller coaster tycoon was written entirely in assembly.

Comment: if you want to work hard every thing is possible..:)

Comment: Of course it's possible.  Everything eventually gets executed as assembly on the CPU.  It won't be *easy*, and you won't have any of the tools available to higher-level languages and frameworks.  But it's possible.

Comment: `are there any programs/softwares to aid the development of games in assembly language` - yes, it's called a _"compiler"_

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys but can I know more specific like why some programmers uses assembly language for games? Any advantages or its disadvantages?

Comment: I don't know any area of application where assembly would be the preferred language today. Maybe some small embedded devices, but even in those cases C is often available. Your productivity in assembly is basically zero if we compare it to the same using a higher level language. There is no need for assembly to develop games. Just go with C/C++ if you want a higher level language that is biased by system programming. Even if you want low level optimization you can do that without asm by using C/C++ intrinsics but very few high profile games need that and only on some platforms.

Comment: @pasztorpisti, OpenBLAS uses assembly http://xianyi.github.io/OpenBLAS/. I don't think it's possible to do as well for GEMM except with assembly.

Comment: @Zboson My statements still hold true. Hand crafted asm is always faster than compiled asm but often the difference is not so high and the development/maintenance cost of asm often isn't worth the trouble. Even if we speak of an app that does scientific calculations: using such a library means that one or more small pieces of your app (eg.: matrix multiplier) are optimized. It is still worth writing the rest of the app in a higher level language. optimization != full-asm

Comment: @pasztorpisti, I agree that it does not make sense to write full applications in assembly. But there is still a need for assembly for some critical functions and even intrinsics may not be sufficient. I guess we don't really disagree. Intrinsics don't always do what you want (e.g. there is no way to specify a fused vs. unfused add and load).

Comment: @Zboson Sure. I'm wondering of what can be the real goal of OP. If it's assembly programming that he is enjoying then no matter what kind of advice we give... He will do it in assembly (just like I did when I started programming...) :-) If the goal is finishing a game in time and perhaps on multiple platforms then its a completely different set of requirements. I'm not against assembly but I've seen too many high profile games driven by legacy lava code that is a pile of crap without any asm... In contrast, many people think that the whole code is beautifully optimized in a game... hehehe

Comment: Not only is it possible but most console games in the Nintendo era were written in 6502 assembly including beloved classics like Metroid (whose 6502 assembly source is now available), Super Mario, Contra, etc, and the entire software basically revolved around the analogical equivalent of global variables. That said, I'm not sure about any real advantage these days to doing that. I still think there's more use for handwritten assembly than people give credit, but maybe not at the scale of an entire game -- you can use it to potentially speed up some very critical loops in isolated areas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in fact it is *possible*. As the saying goes,

> *Anything is possible, if you put your mind to it.*

A rather popular game from a while back, [RollerCoaster Tycoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RollerCoaster_Tycoon#Development) was written almost entirely in x86 assembly, although a few C functions were used to interface with the OS and DirectX.

However, as you might imagine, this can be extremely painful. Higher level languages exist to make things easier. My favorite, `C` is rather commonly used for close-to-the-metal applications, and is considered fairly low level.

Here's an example of a direct translation from a simple C function (bubble sort, one of the simplest of them all) to x64 assembly:

### C ([Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Bubble_sort#C)):

```
void bubble_sort (int *a, int n) {
    int i, t, s = 1;
    while (s) {
        s = 0;
        for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            if (a[i] < a[i - 1]) {
                t = a[i];
                a[i] = a[i - 1];
                a[i - 1] = t;
                s = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### x64 ([Godbolt GCC](http://goo.gl/kpXwWz))

```
bubble_sort:
    push    rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    mov QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rdi
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-28], esi
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
    jmp .L2
.L6:
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
    jmp .L3
.L5:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    lea rdx, [0+rax*4]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add rax, rdx
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    sal rax, 2
    lea rcx, [rax-4]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add rax, rcx
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    cmp edx, eax
    jge .L4
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    lea rdx, [0+rax*4]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add rax, rdx
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-12], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    lea rdx, [0+rax*4]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add rdx, rax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    sal rax, 2
    lea rcx, [rax-4]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add rax, rcx
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdqe
    sal rax, 2
    lea rdx, [rax-4]
    mov rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-24]
    add rdx, rax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-12]
    mov DWORD PTR [rdx], eax
    mov DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 1
.L4:
    add DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 1
.L3:
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cmp eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28]
    jl  .L5
.L2:
    cmp DWORD PTR [rbp-8], 0
    jne .L6
    pop rbp
    ret
```

---

Now, in this day and age, people expect their programs to run quickly. If you;re going to do anything fancy or use a lot of data, you need optimized code. Here's what the same code with full optimizations looks like:

### x64 with full architecture optimizations for a common CPU (`-O3 -march=corei7`; [Godbolt GCC](http://goo.gl/Ql9Urr)):

```
bubble_sort:
    lea eax, [rsi-2]
    cmp esi, 1
    lea r8, [rdi+8+rax*4]
    jg  .L11
    rep; ret
.L11:
    add rdi, 4
.L3:
    mov rax, rdi
    xor esi, esi
.L6:
    mov edx, DWORD PTR [rax]
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [rax-4]
    cmp edx, ecx
    jge .L4
    mov DWORD PTR [rax], ecx
    mov esi, 1
    mov DWORD PTR [rax-4], edx
.L4:
    add rax, 4
    cmp rax, r8
    jne .L6
    test    esi, esi
    jne .L3
    rep; ret
```

Wait a minute. It looks much shorter. Certainly. But can you tell which instructions to put where, how it has reordered the instructions, or what combinations to use? The compiler can.

---

All in all, writing a game in assembly is probably an extremely bad idea. It's a better idea to use a compiled language such as C to write your game and possibly rewrite one or two function by hand in assembly later.

If there really are many common instances where your handwritten assembly outperforms the compiler with max optimizations, perhaps you ought to notify the developers of that compiler, so they can work with you to add the optimization you have in mind. This will allow you to just have the compiler do the same without your intervention in the future.

Compiler intrinsics will often allow you to do many of the things you do in assembly. Hell, you can even write near pure MMX/SSE/SSSE/AVX code by using compiler intrinsics, while letting the compiler still optimize it further, allocate registers well, and integrate it with the rest of your code.

Comment: Some things are still best in assembly https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/tree/develop/kernel/x86_64

Comment: @Zboson certainly. But for a user who has to ask this question, it's probably not a good idea. Also, a decent game is probably a fair bit larger than a few Linear Algebra Subroutines.

Comment: I don't disagree with you, even even +1ed your answer, I just wanted to give an example where assembly is still useful.